# R : how can i add two variables in text on the X axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with countries variables as such

```
location      population        vax
Canada           38067913        345
China           1444216102      3245
Mexico          130262220       5234
```

I thought i could write something like :

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=location,y= vax)+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(location + population))
```

my plot on the X axis should write : Canada 38067913, China 1444216102, Mexico 130262220

thank you

Comment: The "+" function cannot handle character values in R. (You should post all the error messages you get, and I'm pretty sure you got one.)

Answer (score 2):

You can `paste` the two columns -

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x= paste(location, population) ,y= vax)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  xlab('Location')
```

[image]

Comment: but what if it's already ordered like this aes(x=reorder(location,vax)

Comment: You can change that to `aes(x= reorder(paste(location, population),vax)`